# codeception как производить манипуляции с БД перед тестами

Tags: mysql, codeception, функциональное-тестирование

Использую codeception перед тестами нужно заполнить БД тестовыми данными. использую

```
Modules: \Helper\Api, REST, PhpBrowser
```

Перед тестами нужно заполнить БД тестовыми данными логично сделать это в

```
_before() {

}
```

Но как это сделать неясно хочется использовать какой нибудь ДБ адаптер от одного из фреймворков пробовал подключить как модуль фалькон, но все тесты типа таких перестают работать

```
public function testRestWord() {
    $I = $this->tester;
    $postData = [
        "word" => "word",
        "transcription" =>"word trans",
        "ownerId" => "3",
        "status" => "N",
        "moderationStatus" => "3",
        "mainFormId" => "19",
        "createdAt" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "updatedAt" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ];

    $I->wantTo('Create words');
    $I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $I->sendPOST('/words', $postData);
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(\Codeception\Util\HttpCode::OK); // 200
    $I->seeResponseIsJson();
    $I->seeResponseContains('"status":200');
```

Собственно как:

1. Писать в БД через адаптер какого либо фреймворка желательно фалькон
2. Очищасть БД после выполнения тестов

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно чтобы в БД появлялись нужные записи перед тестами? Подключить модуль Db и использовать комманду `$I->haveInDataBase()` Или я вопрос не правильно понял? 
Там же у модуля Db есть свойства для работы с дампами базы, но работал только с cleanup, оно очищает перед запуском каждого теста. Как вернуть дамп после всех тестов не скажу ;(

Comment: Значит так 
Имеем сначала таблицы без тестовых данных

Потом загружаем туда данные через MYSQL запросы 
потом прогоняем тесты после прогона тестов тестовые данные удаляем. 
Или Например такая ситуация я регистрируюсь под определенным email на боевой базе и хочу потом этого юзера удалить при помощи SQL запросов